# Trying to join on set returning function

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to join two tables on IDs extracted from json array of one of the tables, I found some topic on lateral joins but I can't get it, I'm failing to implement it on my case.
Or maybe there's other way to do it?

```
create table jsontable (response jsonb);
insert into jsontable values ('{"SCS":[{"customerId": 100, "referenceId": 215}, {"customerId": 120, "referenceId":544}, {"customerId": 400, "referenceId": 177}]}');

create table message (msg_id integer, status integer, content text);
insert into message values
(544, 1, 'Test'), (134, 1, 'Test2'), (177, 0, 'Test3'), (215, 1, 'Test4');

SELECT m.*
FROM jsontable t
JOIN message m ON m.msg_id = (jsonb_array_elements(t.response -> 'SCS')->>'referenceId')::int
and m.status = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8b3890efd34199f2356b6abca2f811c2

Of course it throws an ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions

Comment: JOIN message m ON m.msg_id IN (SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(t.response -> 'SCS')->>'referenceId')::int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to join against are the individual objects in the array, not the whole row. So use

```
SELECT m.*, obj
FROM jsontable t, jsonb_array_elements(t.response -> 'SCS') obj
JOIN message m ON m.msg_id = (obj->>'referenceId')::int AND m.status = 1;
```

or (a bit more readable imo)

```
SELECT m.*, obj
FROM jsontable t,
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.response -> 'SCS') obj
JOIN message m ON m.msg_id = (obj->>'referenceId')::int
WHERE m.status = 1;
```

<sup>([updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=70c2fb57b9be8e3a145443ed9190ce7e))</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to inner join another tables to jsontable t and so on? Because when I try, it throws an error "There is an entry for table "t", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.", how to trick over it?

Comment: @sh4rkyy You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the failing query. In general, that sounds like a precedence or nesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

`jsonb_array_elements() :: int` returns a set of integer which cannot be equal to one integer `m.msg_id`.

Try instead :

```
SELECT m.*
FROM jsontable t
JOIN message m ON m.msg_id IN (SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(t.response -> 'SCS')->>'referenceId')::int)
and m.status = 1
```